# Kotlin data classes JSON Deserialization

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception

I am trying convert `ApiEmployee` to `Employee` and have written a test around it. I am confused about **nulls** in Kotlin as I am new to it.

`ApiEmployee` would be used for JSON conversion so it can have missing `name` field or or empty or can come as null. In that case, I don't want to add into list and safely ignore it.

I am getting `Method threw 'kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException at exception.` at `apiEmployee.name!!.isNotBlank()`

**ApiEmployee**

```
data class ApiEmployee(val image: String? = "image",
                   val name: String? = "name test",
                   val description: String? = "",
                   val id: String? = "")
```

**Employee**

```
data class Employee(val imagePath: String, val id: String)
```

**EmployeeConverter**(converts ApiEmployee to Employee)

```
fun apply(apiEmployees: List<ApiEmployee>): List<Employee> {
    val employees = mutableListOf<Employee>()
    for (apiEmployee in apiEmployees) {
      if (apiEmployee.name!!.isNotBlank()){
         employees.add(Employee(apiEmployee.image!!, apiEmployee.id!!)
      }
    }
}
```

**EmployeeConverterTest**

```
  @Test
fun `should not add employee without name into employee list`() {
  val invalidApiEmployee = ApiEmployee("image", null, "description", "id")
  val convertedEmployees : List< Employee > =  employeeConverter.apply(listOf( invalidApiEmployee))

  assertThat(convertedEmployees.size).isEqualTo(0)
}
```

Comment: Pass the value for name ...ApiEmployee("image", "name", "description", "id") .. it should work... the default value is overridden by null value ...

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the value for name.

```
ApiEmployee("image", "name", "description", "id")
```

(or)

Change the if condition as mentioned below (with ? operator):-

```
if (apiEmployee.name?.isNotBlank()){
```

> ?. performs a safe call (calls a method or accesses a property if the
>   receiver is non-null)
>
> !! asserts that an expression is
>   non-null

The code asserts that name is not null and checking for not blank.

Probably, I think you are trying to do null and not blank check. You can use `? operator (safe call)` for that. This means `isNotBlank()` gets executed only if the name is not null.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is check if the name is null first and then if it is empty.

```
val employeeNameIsNotEmpty = apiEmployee.name?.isNotBlank() ?: false
if (employeeNameIsNotEmpty) { 
    // do stuff
}
```

The `apiEmployee.name?.isNotBlank()` will run and return a value only if name is not null. If name is null then the statment on the right side of ?: will return its value, which in this case should be false.

In this case however Kotlin has already put this particular example into an extension function

> .isNullOrBlank()

So you could change it to:

```
if (!apiEmployee.name.isNullOrBlank()) { 
    // do stuff
}
```

As a side note you really don't whant to do this `Employee(apiEmployee.image!!, apiEmployee.id!!)`.
Because image and id could still be null and crash your code with the same error.